# Not able to produce burst of audio frequencies in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to create an app in flutter. [Here is the app desc in an google presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1xVqNEbq8cmEngWLucNpQisfLeNg07g6Rx_efWbGGSis/edit#slide=id.g2a8c05cc08c_0_37)

I am trying to re create this burst effect using delayed statements, I am using surround_sound package as I also wanted to use channels (left / right )

The burst is not working properly and not looping , the audio is played only once and then it stops.

Here is my `main.dart`

```
import 'package:audiogen/channelselector.provider.dart';
import 'package:audiogen/homepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ToneGen>(
      create: (context) => ToneGen(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Surround Sound Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

`HomePage`

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:audiogen/widgets/circularradio.dart';
import 'package:audiogen/widgets/playbutton.dart';
import 'package:awesome_number_picker/awesome_number_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:surround_sound/surround_sound.dart';

import 'channelselector.provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _controller = SoundController();

  var isPlaying = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final toneGen = context.read<ToneGen>();
    final frequency = toneGen.frequency;
    final burstDuration = toneGen.burstdurations;
    final selectedChannel = toneGen.selectedChannel;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFD1E3),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SoundWidget(
            soundController: _controller,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          CircleButtons(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            child: IntegerNumberPicker(
              size: 60,
              pickedItemDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xff392467),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
              pickedItemTextStyle:
                  GoogleFonts.inter(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
              axis: Axis.horizontal,
              initialValue: 5,
              minValue: 1,
              maxValue: 11,
              onChanged: (i) => setState(() {
                context.read<ToneGen>().burstdurations = i;
                print(context.read<ToneGen>().burstdurations);
              }),
            ),
          ),
          SoundWidget(
            soundController: _controller,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Play"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Access burst duration from provider (assuming it's available)
                  final burstDuration = context.watch<ToneGen>().burstdurations;
                  print("inside the burst duration" + "$burstDuration");
                  // Start a repeating loop for burst playback
                  void playBurst() async {
                    _controller.setFrequency(5000); // Set frequency
                    _controller.setPosition(
                      // Set position based on selected channel (adjust logic as needed)
                      selectedChannel == 0
                          ? 0.2
                          : selectedChannel == 1
                              ? -0.2
                              : 0,
                      0,
                      0,
                    );
                    await _controller.play();
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: burstDuration));
                    await _controller.stop();
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10 - burstDuration));

                    // Check if still playing before repeating (handle user pausing)
                    if (await _controller.isPlaying()) {
                      playBurst(); // Repeat burst
                    }
                  }

                  // Initiate the burst loop
                  playBurst();

                  // Print playback status (optional for debugging)
                  final val = await _controller.isPlaying();
                  print('isPlaying: $val');
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 24),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Stop"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _controller.stop();
                  final val = await _controller.isPlaying();
                  print('isPlaying: $val');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`provider`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToneGen extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedChannel = 0;
 final int _frequency = 5000;
  int _burstdurations = 5;

  int get selectedChannel => _selectedChannel;
  int get frequency => _frequency;
  int get burstdurations => _burstdurations;
  set selectedChannel(int newValue) {
    _selectedChannel = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  set burstdurations(int newValue) {
    _burstdurations = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Circle Button

```
import 'package:audiogen/channelselector.provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CircleButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const CircleButtons({super.key});

  @override
  State<CircleButtons> createState() => _CircleButtonsState();
}

class _CircleButtonsState extends State<CircleButtons> {
  int selectedButton = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
            ),
            Text("Left",
                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                    fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedButton = 0;
                  context.read<ToneGen>().selectedChannel = selectedButton;
                  // Assuming 0 represents the left circle
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Color(0xffA367B1)),
                  color: selectedButton == 0
                      ? Color(0xffA367B1)
                      : Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 150,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
            ),
            Text("Right",
                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                    fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedButton = 1;
                  context.read<ToneGen>().selectedChannel =
                      selectedButton; // Assuming 1 represents the right circle
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.green),
                  color: selectedButton == 1
                      ? Color(0xffA367B1)
                      : Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`Pubspec.yaml`

```
name: audiogen
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  awesome_number_picker: ^0.0.4
  audioplayers: ^5.2.1
  sound_generator: ^0.0.9
  surround_sound: ^0.3.2
  provider: ^6.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```